# rxjs - 2 API calls (shallow call vs deep call)

Tags: rxjs

I have 2 calls.  First call and second call.

Second call takes longer 99% of the time and once it's complete has all the info I need.  But I call first call which is quick and limited info to appease user.

If Second call finishes before first - cancel first call.

How do i achieve this?

```
let myResult$ = someOperator([
myApiService.call1(),
myApiService.call2()]).pipe(
    //do something after each call completes (twice in Total)
);
```

Comment: use `merge` operator

Answer (score 1):

As Oles Savluk correctly points out:

```
let myResult$ = merge([
    myApiService.call1(),
    myApiService.call2()
]);
```

Note that it results in two single, separate values in the observable. If you need the result of both requests in one value array, use [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin).
Do not forget to subscribe / unsubscribe to `myResult$`.

**EDIT**: Untested, but if you want to give superiority to one of the observables:

```
let superior$ = myApiService.call1();
let inferior$ = myApiService.call2();
let myResult$ = merge([superior$, inferior$]).pipe(
    takeUntil(superior$)    
);
```

The `merge` makes sure both observables get their shot, and he `takeUntil` makes sure that if the superior comes first, the result will finish immediately.

Comment: any idea how i can give precedence to call 2?  Say call 2 is a deeper search but in some odd instances it may return quicker.  Then I want to ignore call 1.  But 99% time call 1 will be faster.

Comment: RxJS has a solution as well: The _race_ operator:  `let myResult$ = race([myApiService.call1(),myApiService.call2()]);` It will ignore the slowest call, and even clean up that subscription for you.

Comment: race takes only 1 - but what im looking for is - call 1 emits and then call 2 emits with more info (original merge answer) but in the event call 2 emits before call 1, dont let call 1 emit and possibly cancel)

Comment: I see, I updated my answer such that it suits your specific problem

Comment: Seems like this answer has issues - the superior call gets called twice.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1.** 
I like `@Wouter van Koppen`'s asnwer, yet few changes would make it great:

```js
const long$ = myApiService.longOperation().pipe(share()) 
const short$ = myApiService.shortOperation$.pipe(takeUntil(long$))

merge(long$, short$).subscribe(console.log);
```

`share` is used so that `takeUntil(long$)` and `merge(long$` would share the same subscription thus preventing `longOperation` from getting subscribed twice.

**Option 2.**

```js
shortOperation$
.pipe(
  takeUntil(
    longOperation$.pipe(
      tap(x => {
       // run some code
      })
    )
  )
)
.subscribe(console.log);
```